# How to automatically set a mysql column to equal an operation on another?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want one row in my mysql table to always equal the difference of another two, but the only way i seem to be able to do it is by setting it first time to 0 and then running an update command. Is there anyway to just automate this behaviour so i never have to think about it? Appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to investigate using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html), which are set to run whenever a particular operation occurs on another database object. e.g.,

```
CREATE TRIGGER foobar AFTER UPDATE ON table
  FOR EACH ROW SET foo = foo + NEW.bar;
```

Comment: +1, many databases offer calculated columns, but MySQL is not one of them.  Triggers are probably your only option here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a view:

```
create vw_table as
    select t.*, (col2 - col1) as diff
    from t;
```

The view will then do the calculation when it is used, so the results are always up-to-date.  You don't need to store the data in separate columns.

The downside is that you cannot create a column on the result (in MySQL).  For that, you need a separate column, maintained as described by Gian.

Answer (score 0):

What is the use case with this?

For the sake of database integrity you want to avoid having dependent values in case something goes awry. It's one of those things where I didn't see the point of at first but after cleaning up have a bit of respect for.

If you're sure it what you want, and you can use a trigger to say anytime this is updated update this.